# Is there a way to know the font type used by console and its location in linux?

Tags: linux, fonts

Anyone knows how to trace this?

I'm learning the way font works by doing this BTW.

Comment: What do you mean by console? The text one (no X), or an X terminal?

Comment: Does `setfont -v` help?

Answer (score 1):

It uses [PSF](http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/kbd/font-formats-1.html), the fonts are traditonally located under `/usr/share/consolefonts`.

There is no way to tell "which font is the current one", in the sense that once a font has been loaded, the file itself could be modified or removed. You can, however, figure out which font is loaded by default by looking at your distribution-specific configuration files; or, you could use `setfont -o <file>` to dump the loaded font to a file.

Comment: There's no such file...

Comment: sorry, typo, it was consolefontS. It was there on most distributions I tried, which one are you using ?

Comment: I'm on Fedora release 8,and there is no such file ...

Comment: Ah, `/lib/kbd/consolefonts` then.

Comment: This directory do exist, but how do I know which font is the current one?